# SQL Server image column data - can copy and paste?

Tags: sql-server

I am having trouble trying to render images from an `Image` column in SQL Server. I got the image data from a client db using straight copy and paste from the grid results, as we had trouble with the export process.

I am aware that there is truncation happening after 65k, but is there any other reason why you can't copy from one `Image` column grid data result and paste into another? And if so, is there another way to copy the data apart from `Tasks > Export`?

Note, when I extract the mime-type from the `byte[]` array, it comes back as `text/plain`, so I'm also hoping that there isn't some special behaviour required by the original coders to treat the data.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? The maximum size for `IMAGE` columns is 2^30 - 1 (1,073,741,823) bytes, not 65k.

Additionally, can you simply upload the images onto your server somewhere (or just them where they are) and instead store a URL? Storing images in binary is bad; it damages performance when trying to select large numbers of rows from the table, and the `IMAGE` datatype is going to be removed in future versions of SQL Server. Since you're doing maintenance anyway, your best option is to fix the column. Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx

Comment: I am trying to pull data from one db behind a DMZ into another local development db, so they can't talk to each other, hence the copy and paste.  I am copying straight from the grid results page through RDC/MSTSC and pasting into my local machine, hence the 65k limit.

Comment: And I can't edit the original table, as it's being used for other systems, and we're simply displaying data that's already in there.  For now I am developing against a local copy until we deploy and point to the live db that I'm copying from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using a SQL statement to do the update instead:

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.Col_Image = (SELECT table2.Col_Image FROM table2 WHERE table2.ID = 2)
FROM table1 
WHERE table1.ID = 1
```

Comment: The databases can't see each other.

Comment: Might be a bit excessive, but can you take backup the db file and restore it locally to run an update?

Comment: Option considered and avoided. My problem is that my copy-and-pasted data is not working, and I'm trying to determine if the problem is copy-and-pasting, or if there are other problems with the data.

Comment: Ended up going with this approach, borrowing other image data on the system, as it became clear that copy and paste has a corrupting effect on data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried INSERT...SELECT, to select the image for the table #1 and insert them into table #2?

```
insert into Table2 (Id2, NewImageField)
select Id1, OriginalImage
from table1
where Id1 = 1
```

Comment: The databases can't see each other, as per my comment on the question.